# How can I change the default wiki page template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki, template, default-document

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Online (as part of a Office365 subscription). I've just added the *Wiki Page Library* app, now I find I want to modify the template that is used for new pages in the wiki.

Specifically the modifications that really interest me are:

- I want to remove the page title from the rendered page (this doesn't show when in edit mode or when editing the page source)
- I want to add some styles to the *Format Text* ribbon options

What do I need to do to accomplish this? Do I need any specific permissions?